# Compare Folders in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm using TFS and C# and I want to programmatically get a list of files that have changed between 2 different folders.
I want to be able to enter the path & label, just like the Compare option in the Source Control Explorer in Visaul Studio.
thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the answer, however the API you suggested is internal.

I was able to find an great example of how to do this called [Diffing two trees in TFS version control](http://blogs.msdn.com/roberthorvick/archive/2006/04/07/571043.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.FolderDiff.  Unfortunately it's marked internal-only.  You'll have to bust open Reflector and access it the "fun" way.

Alternatively, you could parse the output of **tf.exe folderdiff $/folder1 $/folder2**.